# What do I need to install to get Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll?

Tags: .net, tfs, visual-studio-sdk

Do I simply need to install the [VS2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5)?

Is there such a thing as the TFS2010 SDK, and if so, would *that* be the thing I need to install, and if so, where can I get it?

On Microsoft's ["Extend Visual Studio" web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/vextend.aspx), I saw a link to [example code for the "TFS 2010 SDK"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk) but I could not find the TFS 2010 SDK itself.

---

The reason I am asking: I am building a codebase that is not mine, which depends on Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to install the TFS Team Explorer (i.e. the TFS client tools).

Installing the VS2010 SDK will add documentation etc., but the assemblies come from the client itself.

Comment: I found them in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies` on my machine.

Comment: @Cheeso they should also be in the GAC... as normal ReferenceAssemblies are only used for development & build.

Comment: This assembly did seem to be included with Visual Studio Team Explorer, but there are others that don't seem to readily available anywhere (that I could find). See my [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545757/where-is-the-tfs-2010-api-dll-microsoft-teamfoundation-framework-server-dll) for one example.

Answer (score 26):

For anyone looking for this in Visual Studio 2012, you can add references without an external download:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

For visual studio 2015

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/

You can have more details for another similar assembly here:

[Where can I find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138669/where-can-i-find-microsoft-teamfoundation-build-client-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Great package!
It's also needed for other TFS package ("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ObjectModel") to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can find it here :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies
```

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2017, the Assemblies are here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS 2015 and I found this dll file on path --

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\
```