# Where is the TFS 2010 API DLL Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.dll?

Tags: tfs

This DLL is needed to reference the corresponding namespace [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server%28v=vs.100%29). This DLL doesn't seem to be included with either the Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer or the Visual Studio 2010 Team Foundation Server SDK.

Answer (score 4):

This file can be copied from the server where Team Foundation Server 2010 is installed in the folder *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services\bin*.

Answer (score 4):

The official place is

> \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0

But I used:

> \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0

because I'm on 64-bit Windows and I have VS2013.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.aspx

Answer (score 2):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies is the location for TestManagment client. But, you may need to download the stand-alone TeamExplorer first...  Thanks Microsoft :(

[image]