# Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataSTore32.dll'

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, iis-7

I can see some have the same problem as I but I have not found a solution on the problem that fixes it for me.

This works on my dev-machine but not in production:

```
WorkItemStore workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Here is my error message:

```
Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I have copied the file into my bin-folder but it still not work.Could this be anything with IIS-process-user not having access to the file? Where to start?

Anyone experienced the same?

Regards.

Comment: Related post - [Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll' (TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31031817/465053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow down if the issue related to IIS-process-user not having access to the file.

You could check the permissions on the dll. Make sure the **Network Service** and **app pool identity** both had **read/write/execute** permissions.  Add IIS_IUSRS, IIS-process-users with r/w/x.

Please also try to run the cmd `tasklist /m dll_name.dll` to check whether another process has the file locked and without share-read access.

In another direction is double checking if add reference to `Microsoft.WITDataStore` successful. If you are using Nuget Package to install the dll, please make sure using the [official NuGet packages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2015/08/10/nuget-packages-for-tfs-and-visual-studio-online-net-client-object-model/). Some similar question about this for your reference:

- [Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll' (TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031817/unable-to-load-dll-microsoft-witdatastore32-dll-teamfoundation-workitemtracki)
- [TFS 2015 SDK Missing Microsoft.WITDataStore64.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128581/tfs-2015-sdk-missing-microsoft-witdatastore64-dll)
- [How to solve Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.WITDataStore'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135086/how-to-solve-failed-to-add-reference-to-microsoft-witdatastore)

Comment: The app pool identity had lost its rights to the bin-folder. Setting correct access for the identity solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Nuget package for TFS Integration. If you add the TFS Extended Client it will setup the files in the necessary way.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient

It adds two additional files to your project that you need.