# Unable to load DLL Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll, however DLL is in bin directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

```
Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

The other answers I see regarding this issue say that copying them to the bin directory is the solution. I clearly can see mine in the bin directory. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the TFS extended nuget package, cleaned, rebuilt, etc. just about 50 times now.

This error only occurs at runtime. The solution builds just fine.

Besides burning the whole thing to the ground what are some ways I could resolve this issue?

```
namespace (mynamespace)
{
    class TFSConnection
    {
        string tfsUrl = "(tfsurl)";
        string project = "(tfsProject)";
        public ITestManagementTeamProject GetProject()
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(tfsUrl));
            ITestManagementService tms = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();

            return tms.GetTeamProject(project);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the piece of code that's attempting to access this module.

Comment: @PMF I've added my code above (with sanitizing). It is throwing at the `tms.GetTeamProject()` according to the stack trace. Tracing all the way back to `DataStoreNative32.CreateDatastore(IntPtr& handle)`

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? And which version of VS are you using? Including copy the DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll' to the bin folder, you could also try other solution in the following case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031817/unable-to-load-dll-microsoft-witdatastore32-dll-teamfoundation-workitemtracki

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT TFS 2015 and migrating a project from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015.

Comment: Is your project working in VS 2013? Which version of TFS extended nuget package did you install?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT It works on 2013 fine but the required extended libraries for 2015 do not. This issue in this thread is what I get when using the solution in 2015 with the latest version of the nuget package.

Comment: How about using TFS extended nuget package 12.0?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT That package targets older versions of visual studio does it not? I was told it won't work in 2015 and higher.

Comment: @Reed Sorry, I mean if you use TFS extended nuget package 14.0 and copy the Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll to the bin folder as this case describe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031817/unable-to-load-dll-microsoft-witdatastore32-dll-teamfoundation-workitemtracki

Answer (score 0):

You can get the given exception even if the indicated file *is* actually there, but it's *dependencies* are not. If the package comes with more dlls (which I assume, because it seems to be a C# wrapper somehow), make sure these are also in the bin folder.

Unfortunately, if a native dll is missing, .NET will not tell you which one is missing, but instead return the name of the last managed DLL in the stack trace.

Comment: So how can I find out what dependencies the solution is missing then?

Comment: There's no easy way to determine that. I remember having a lot of try-until-it-works last time when I had this problem (in an unrelated context). For your particular case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031817/unable-to-load-dll-microsoft-witdatastore32-dll-teamfoundation-workitemtracki?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes I have seen that thread but it doesn't apply because the DLL is very clearly in my bin directory. There are over 75 projects in this single solution so trial and error isn't ideal unfortunately.

Comment: You might be able to get some more information if you attach the debugger in "mixed" (native) mode. Or use SysInternals Process Monitor to find out which file it tries to open.