# Is TFS 2013 compatible with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am trying to connect to TFS 2013 with VS 2017 via c#. But I could not able to connect and I am getting WITdatastore32.dll is missing.

Can you someone please let me know is it possible to connect to TFS 2013 with VS 2017, if so, what are the steps to be followed?

Comment: I have installed VS Ultimate 2013 and it is working as expected. I try to install Team Explorer 2013 and add the references with V S2017, may be it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install Team Explorer 2013 on your machine. After installation, you need to `Browse...` for the references here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies
```

Check the poster's answer in case [Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll' (TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031817/unable-to-load-dll-microsoft-witdatastore32-dll-teamfoundation-workitemtracki)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements?view=vsts#client-compatibility), the combination of TFS 2013 and Visual Studio 2017 can count on *high level of support*. Later in the same article, you'll find the [description of that term](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements?view=vsts#high-level-of-support). In particular:

> If you are using newer versions of Visual Studio against older versions of Team Foundation Server, you can similarly expect most features to be supported.

However, you should still consider upgrading the TFS instance on a regular basis, since the distance between VS and TFS versions will increase if you only upgrade VS, and thus the level of support will decrease. Take a look at the first image in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-update2) to understand the upgrade path you should take.

Comment: I could able to connect to TFS but when getting the project name from TFS I am getting ' Could not load WISTDataStore32.dll' error message.