# Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll' (TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking) Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, coded-ui-tests

I have VS 2017 enterprise and I use VSTS.OS - Windows Server 2012 R2
Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll is a native dll so we can not add it as a reference

**Problem** :

When I am trying to run coded UI test in my VS 2017 enterprise
I get the error message "Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" at

```
iTestManagementService.GetTeamProject("Project Name")
```

Stack Trace for this is

```
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DataStoreNative32.CreateDatastore(IntPtr& handle)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DataStoreNative.CreateDatastore(IntPtr& handle)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ITfsTeamProjectCollectionObject.Initialize(TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.InitializeTeamFoundationObject(String fullName, Object instance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.CreateServiceInstance(Assembly assembly, String fullName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.GetWitProject()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.get_WitHelper()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.get_SharedParameterDataSetWorkItemTypeName()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.get_HasSupportForSharedParameterDataSets()
```

I had already installed Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient -Version 15.112.1 nuget package. And it has the dll present in it but somehow it is not able to load it.

I also installed TeamExplorer as someone suggested but no luck

Below are the paths where Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll and Microsoft.WITDataStore64 dlls are present in my machine

1. Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
2. Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
3. packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient.15.112.1\lib\native\x86

This Question is already present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031817/unable-to-load-dll-microsoft-witdatastore32-dll-teamfoundation-workitemtracki) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23eeb78e-8dcc-4160-a02e-fab63ef104b1/unable-to-load-dll-microsoftwitdatastore32dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found?forum=tfsgeneral) but its answers did not fix my issues.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Is `Microsoft.WITDataStore64.dll` stored in `packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient.15.112.1\lib\native\amd64`? Do you try to reboot your machine?

Comment: yes the 64 dll is present and also I did tried with reboot as well

Comment: Just a test, if you manually add Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll to system32 folder, will it work?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT No it won't work as it is a native dll. And when I try to add it it gives me error message that "Please make sure the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component"

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue on another machine?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I don't have other machine to try it on to.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side. I'm using VS 15.5.2, do you use the same version?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I have VS Enterprise 2017 version 15.7.1
have you installed nuget package also which I have installed?

Comment: Yes, I installed `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient 15.112.1`, but I didn't get any error at `iTestManagementService`.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I also have this issue in VS 2017 Enterprise 15.5.6 with the nuget package 15.112.1

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT did you able to connect to the team project and also did you get any error at this line of code? iTestManagementService.GetTeamProject("Project Name")