# Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll':The specified module could not be found.(Exception from HRESULT:0x8007007E)

Tags: c#

I am getting error while debugging the Unit test cased in Visual Studio 2017 Professional edition.

> Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll':The specified module could not be found.(Exception from HRESULT:0x8007007E)

The below Nuget reference is missing in the existing code:

> package id="nuget-bot.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader" version="15.0.31101" targetFramework="net452" />

As a workaround, I have followed the below step:

Commented the above nuget-bot reference from package.config file and managing the Nuget package from the VS solution. I am using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient.15.112.1` in the solution.

But the issue is still occurring

Comment: Related post - [Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll' (TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31031817/465053)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you to use version 15.0.31101 and you're using 15.112.1. Try using the exact version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not getting version 15.0.31101 of the file. Could you please provide the link to download the same version of the file.